# Send email with Office365 python library `python-o365`

Tags: python, office365

Ok So ive been able to send mail and read mail but I am now trying to attach an attachment to the mail and it doesnt seem to append the document as expected. I dont get any errors but I also dont get the mail if I attempt to add the attachment.

The library im using is [here](https://github.com/Narcolapser/python-o365)

The returned value frome the function is `True` but an email never arrives if i remove the `m.attachments.append('/path/to/data.xls')` line the email arrives as expected (without an attachment of course).

**Code**

```
def sendAddresses(username, password):
    try:
        authenticiation = (username, password)
        m = Message(auth=authenticiation)
        m.attachments.append('/path/to/data.xls')
        m.setRecipients("email@address.com")
        m.setSubject("Test Subject")
        m.setBody("Test Email")
        m.sendMessage()
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Could you check if the logfile `o365.log` is created? Perhaps you will find useful informations inside.

Answer (score 0):

Please debug this way

```
att = Attachment(path=path)
att.save(path)
m.attachments.append(att)
```

Comment: attaches fine but m.sendmessage() returns false, no idea why

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to help. It looks like you may be having a problem related to [this](https://github.com/Narcolapser/python-o365/issues/41). Seth had the basic idea right. Make an attachment, then append the attachment to the message.

You say that the message is failing to send. Can you post the contents of o365.log that is created when you call the send function? That would help. Also, try updating to the latest version (0.9.4 at time of writing) and see if that doesn't fix some of your problems.